# Joining 2 tables with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

`poll_opts` table for storing options and `poll_voted` for storing vote result, pid stands for poll id(unique) and oid stands for option id(unique for individual poll only)

`poll_voted` [Primary Key: pid.oid.emp]

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| pid | oid | emp   |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

`poll_opts`  [Primary Key: pid.oid]

```
+-----+-----+---------+
| pid | oid | opt     |
+-----+-----+---------+
```

pid & oid type: `int` , `opt` type: `text`

[image: table data]

Comment: dont join tables in the where clause, use proper join syntax. which key(s)? are used to correlate poll_voted to poll_opts

Comment: @PatrickArtner pid can be used. pid stands for poll id(unique) and oid stands for option id(unique for each poll only)

Comment: what are you looking for? Gordon Linoff provided you with a statement. If it has "wrong" output it might be you did not say what your expected output is? your `poll_voted` does not contain entries for any oid of poll1 so when joining not all will be accounted for unless you use some kind of left join which makes not much sense for the data. also grouping does not make much sense as each group contains only one element so grouping does nothing for you...

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've added details. Hope this helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the "not existent" results as well you need a `left outer join` preserves all results from `poll_opts` even if no match in `poll_votes` is found.

[MySql 5.7 Join Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Query:

```
select opt, count(vo.oid) 
from poll_opts po
left outer join poll_voted vo on vo.oid = po.oid and po.pid=vo.pid
where po.pid = 3 -- 3 
group by opt
```

Output:

```
opt       count(vo.oid)
Chrome    0
Firefox   0
IE        0
MS Edge   0
Opera     1
```

Testdata:

```
CREATE TABLE poll_voted    (`pid` int, `oid` int, `emp` int);

INSERT INTO poll_voted     (`pid`, `oid`, `emp`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 1989),
    (1, 2, 1989),
    (1, 4, 1989),
    (1, 6, 1989),
    (3, 2, 1989)  
;


CREATE TABLE poll_opts     (`pid` int, `oid` int, `opt` varchar(15));

INSERT INTO poll_opts      (`pid`, `oid`, `opt`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'WinXP'),
    (1, 2, 'wIN7'),
    (1, 4, 'wIN 10'),
    (1, 6, 'Ubuntu'), 
    (3, 0, 'IE'),
    (3, 1, 'MS Edge'),
    (3, 2, 'Opera'),
    (3, 3, 'Chrome'),
    (3, 4, 'Firefox')
;
```